# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 How to fix error

Tags: python, string, random, int, literals

```
import random
import operator


op = {"+":operator.add,
      "-":operator.sub,
      "*":operator.mul}
num1 = random.randint(0,10)
num2 = random.randint(0,10)
ops = random.choice(list(op.keys()))
print (num1 + int(ops) + num2)
```

I am trying to make a random math question quiz and I cannot work out why I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:/Computer science/A453/Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print (num1 + int(ops) + num2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
>>> ================================
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a random choice from `'+'`, `'-'` and `'*'` to an integer? What on earth did you *expect* would happen?!

Comment: How could a string like e.g. `"+"` ever be converted to an integer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg only in 2.x, in 3.x you need e.g. `list(op)` rather than `op.keys()` as you can't index a `dict_keys` object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What could i do to fix this then, cause i'm completely baffled

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to call the function keyed with e.g. `"+"` (i.e. `operator.add`)?

Comment: @JonathanDoby how about **don't** try to convert `op` to an integer? Assuming that you, like everyone else here with a similar question, are cheating on your GCSEs and you therefore want to add the three elements together for a single display, try e.g. `print(str(num1) + ops + str(num2))` or, simpler, `print(num1, ops, num2)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, there is a language which would convert `'+'` to `0`.

Comment: @myaut well, perhaps, but Python certainly doesn't!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am trying to get it so it will print it as a math question with the "+" then later it will be able to get the correct answer.

Comment: Then remember that the key already *is* a string, so printing it is easy: Just print it!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The "+" is a string which has a function

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but it needs to do random questions so one time it could be "+" the next time it could be "*"

Comment: It doesn't matter *which* key is selected, they are all strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing string on num1 and num2 instead. Since you're pringing with + you should operate with strings.

```
print (str(num1) + ops + str(num2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was the only thing i didn't try, much appreciated :)